# Container inside SingleChildScrollView doesnt show up without defining width and height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview

I have a body of scaffold that structured like this :

```
body : Column(
children : [
Expanded(
  child : SingleChildScrollView(
  Container (
    Column( 
    //content
    )
  )
  )
),
BottomMenu()
]
)
```

And the problem is the content would not show up if i dont define the width and height for the Container inside SingleChildScrollView, but if i define the height then the height of my childscrollview wont work dynamically with the content, i want the height to fit the content inside of my container so i can scroll until the end of content. I am still new to this so any advice and suggestion will be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: It is hard to tell what is the layout that you are trying to achieve. Can you post a picture describing what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Stack instead of the column as top Widget like this:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    SingleChildScrollView(
      Container (
        Column( 
          //content
        )
      )
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: BottomMenu(),
    ),
 ],
)
```

Does this help you?

Comment: this actually help, but the problem is part of singlechildscrollview content would be covered by bottomenu

Comment: then add padding to the bottom of singlechildscrollview

Answer (score 0):

Your layout isn't best practice, try:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: constraints.maxWidth,
          height: constraints.maxHeight,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              //your content
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }));
```

This makes a container which is the size of the screen, and it contains a column which will scroll with all the content.

Answer (score -1):

I could not understand what exactly the issue is. But I could give some idea.

Try something like this,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          height: 100.0,
                          width: 100.0,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                     
                    
                    ....
                    
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
            child: BottomMenu(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope that solves your issue.